# Add custom filed to a registration form and save it to customer account

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, registration

I have followed this article to create a new customer attribute and add it to the registration form: http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-1-3-how-to-make-customer-attribute-update.html

This is my `InstallData.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author     Sashas IT Support <support@sashas.org>
 * @copyright  2017  Sashas IT Support Inc. (http://www.extensions.sashas.org)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0  GNU General Public License, version 3 (GPL-3.0)
 */


namespace Sashas\CustomerAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();

        $attributesInfo = [
            'magento_username' => [
                'label' => 'Magento Username',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'input' => 'text',
                'position' => 1000,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'system' => 0,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position' => 1000,
            ]
        ];

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
        }

        $magentoUsernameAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magento_username');
        $magentoUsernameAttribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create'],
        ]);

        $magentoUsernameAttribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();

    }
}
```

And added this to my `register.phtml`:

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
  <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>
  <div class="field my_attribute required">
    <label for="magento_username" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Magento Username') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
      <input type="text" name="magento_username" id="magento_username" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Magento Username') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Now, the new "Magento Username" filed appeared on the registration form. However, when checking the table `customer_entity` the column is missing. Or the new attribute will be located in different location?

In which table will will the new attribute be located? Also, how can I retrieve this information passed with registration form? IO would like to display the information in the account information section.

I am open for new solution too, any suggestions will be appreciated.

I am using **Magento ver. 2.2.4**

Comment: May be this one help you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232723/magento-2-how-to-create-custom-field-in-user-registration-page/232733

Comment: I might consider purchasing this module if I can't find a solution :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution for it. It is similar to your requirement.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691720/magento2-custom-attribute-is-not-saving-during-customer-registration-from-fronte

Comment: still nothing :/

Comment: Please  donot put a single link anwer